# How to get USB Resistive touchscreen to work on Android.

Tags: android, usb, linux-device-driver, drivers, touchscreen

I know most of you may have seen that there are a lot of Android based PC on a stick going around. The are very small, but of course, have no input device. They use Android 4.0 and up. The two that I am using are the MK802 (Android 4.0) and the MK808 (Android 4.1). I am trying to use these devices in a mobile/car environment. These units make excellent and affordable car pc units. I already had a Windows based system in the car, so I have all the VGA based screens. They come with 4-wire resistive USB touch panels.

I, of course, plug the USB into the units, but nothing happens. What do I have to do to enable and get the touch screens to work? I would have thought it would be native and or install as a mouse, but that isnt the case. I know that there is a universal driver in Linux that works, but no clue to get it into Android. Also what location do I look in to maybe edit the current drivers in Android?

Any type of help would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to this, so please dont bash me with tons of Android talk, please dumb it down if you can.

Answer (score 0):

To make a new device work in Android is not that easy...Android is not really a universal OS yet, and its kernel is not identical to the kernel we run on desktop.

Here are just some suggestions:

After plugging the USB device, do "adb shell dmesg" to check if linux found a correct driver for you or not. I know there are usbtouchscreen.c lying in kernel source tree(driver/input/touchscreen), but you have to confirm that:

a. The driver itself supports your device
b. The device your Android runs on has compiled & linked this driver module.

For a I assume you have already confirmed.
For b, you can find out by listing all the related drivers from directories like /sys/class/input/driver/... and check if that specific driver is there.

After that, do "adb logcat|grep EventHub" to see if Android is happy with this input device. I think if you can make driver work in linux, there should be not too many problems for Android because it just interact with kernel input from /dev/input/eventX node.

Good luck!